# Cannot find buildozer.spec when run via docker on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, docker, kivy, buildozer

#### Versions

- Python: 3.10.8
- OS: Windows 10
- Buildozer: 1.4.0

#### Description

I am on Windows 10 and installed Docker. And followed the instructions here: https://hub.docker.com/r/kivy/buildozer.
The buildozer.spec file is not created and not found.

#### buildozer.spec

Command:

```bash
docker run -v "C:\GitHub\MyApp:/GitHub/MyApp" buildozer init
```

This gives me the output:
File buildozer.spec created, ready to customize!

But no buildozer.spec is created and when I run:

```bash
docker run -v "C:\GitHub\MyApp:/GitHub/MyApp" buildozer android debug
```

It gives me the output:
No buildozer.spec found in the current directory. Abandon.

I already tried to put a buildozer.spec in the folder "C:\GitHub\MyApp"
But I then still get the output:
No buildozer.spec found in the current directory. Abandon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your host volume is not mounted to the correct directory in the buildozer docker container.

Try changing:

`docker run -v "C:\GitHub\MyApp:/GitHub/MyApp" buildozer init`

To:
`docker run -v "C:\GitHub\MyApp:/home/user/hostcwd" buildozer init`

The reason I think this will work, is because if I look at the Dockerfile for buildozer, it's setting WORKDIR to `ENV WORK_DIR="${HOME_DIR}/hostcwd"`
https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/Dockerfile

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Zoro_77! This seemed to be the problem! I was struggling so much before that I completely overlooked this simple thing! Thanks again!